# template template function instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

```
template < typename T >
class CLASS_TEMPLATE { } ;

template < template < typename T > class CLASS >
void funcI ( ) { } 

template void funcI < CLASS_TEMPLATE > () ;
```

How does compiler instantiate the function, if he does not have any hint about CLASS_TEMPLATE template arguments?

---

My assumptions about template template were wrong.

Formal **template parameter** of `funcI` **is template** with one template parameter.

```
template < template < typename... > class CONTAINER >
void funcII ( ) 
{
   CONTAINER< int > container0 ;
   CONTAINER< float > container1 ;
   /* ... */
}
```

`template void funcII < std::vector > () ;` will instantiate `funcII` template as `{ std::vector< int > container0 ; std::vector< float > container1 ; /* ... */ }` ;

Comment: What kind of trouble would you expect?

Comment: troubles with understanding and troubles with linking. if i can suppose , that respective statement with "extern template" means that all "func" functions with arguments-classes templated from CLASS_TEMPLATE will not be implicitly compiled in the object file, for this statement ( with only "template" ) i cannot suppose anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By explicitly instantiating

```
template void func < CLASS_TEMPLATE > () ;
```

You are effectively doing this:

```
template <>
void func<CLASS_TEMPLATE>() { }
```

There is no need to have the template parameters for `CLASS_TEMPLATE` to do that.

Comment: and it will be implicitly compiled for all CLASS_TEMPLATE classes , right.?

Comment: @GreenTree: It is compiled for the one CLASS_TEMPLATE template, not for any particular class.